# How to increase swap space on RHEL7

Tags: rhel

```
df -h

Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol00_root  2.0G  929M  1.1G  46% /
devtmpfs                        3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           3.9G  8.6M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol00_usr    10G  3.1G  6.9G  31% /usr
/dev/sda2                      1014M  189M  826M  19% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol00_home  2.0G   33M  2.0G   2% /home
/dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol00_tmp   5.0G   89M  5.0G   2% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol00_var   5.0G  707M  4.3G  14% /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol00_opt   6.0G  1.3G  4.8G  21% /opt
tmpfs                           781M     0  781M   0% /run/user/1000
```

How to increase swap space from 3.9G to 10G.
The available RAM is 8G.

Comment: In `/etc/fstab` what is the line about swap? What is the result of `lvs`?

Comment: Seems there's a confusion between swap and RAM based (or swap based...) filesystem. This hinders the possible answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, **swap** is some storage resource other than RAM.  You state *the available RAM is 8gb*.  What you see as `tmpfs` under the Filesystem column is RAM, not SWAP.

Per your output of the `df -h` command, that shows file systems and SWAP is not a file system.

Know that all your `tmpfs` mounts as 3.9gb as `/dev/shm` and `/run` and `/sys/fs/cgroup` is a **dynamic** allocation of RAM.  What this means is it will use at most 3.9gb of RAM for each of those mount points.   There are three mount points, thus if you were to fill each mount point somehow then 3.9 + 3.9 + 3.9 = 11.7gb which is more than your total physical RAM of 8gb.  Fill any of those and exceed the total physical ram and system will halt, but I would not worry about these *tmpfs* numbers they are typically automatically generated by RHEL at install time and are never a problem.

A typical entry in `/etc/fstab` for **swap** would be something like `/dev/sda2 swap    swap    defaults    0   0`  where `/dev/sda2` is partition 2 on the disk at *N* gigabytes.  So if you have this in your `/etc/fstab` then verify how much *SWAP* you actually have, then to increase it your options are

1. repartition that disk so you have some larger partition that you can mount as swap *{typically not possible and not easy to do since never free disk left over}*
2. add another disk and format and mount that as swap *{probably better to spend the money on more ram unless you have spare disks and unused SATA ports}*
3. if you truly need swap space and cannot increase RAM abouve 8gb then create a *swap file* per https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/s1-swap-adding **or** https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s2-swap-creating-file.html **or** https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/how-to-add-swap-space/

Comment: also, if you have just one disk then look at all the partitions on it and find which one is formatted as *swap*.  How big that partition is, is how much swap you currently have to work with.  And the `mount` command *i think* might show a disk partition mounted as swap and the size of it.

Answer (score 2):

You might have two scenarios here. The easiest one is if your swap partition is an LVM partition. Check in `/etc/fstab` to see if `/dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol00-swap` (or something like it is mounted as swap. If so, then run

```
sudo swapoff /dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol00-swap
sudo lvresize -L 10G /dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol00-swap
sudo mkswap /dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol00-swap
sudo swapon -a
```

If you don't have a partition defined for swap, you can use a swap file. Pick a partition that has lots of space (let's choose `/home`)

```
sudo fallocate -l 10G /home/swapfile 
sudo mkswap /home/swapfile
echo "/home/swapfile    none    swap    sw    0   0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
sudo swapon -a
```

Both solutions will persist past a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This post is informational of how to view your current swap configuration, which is important information not covered in the above posts:

To view current swap:

```
cat /proc/swaps
```

For example:

```
$ cat /proc/swaps
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-2               partition   8204284 344320  -
```

And to find out what /dev/dm-2 points to view the contents of /dev/mapper; the directory used by device mapper (dm) for things such as dm-crypt, dm-raid, dm-multipath:

```
$ ll /dev/mapper/
total 0
crw-------. 1 root root 10, 236 Feb 11 08:35 control
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       7 Feb 11 08:35 fedora_localhost--live-home -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       7 Feb 11 08:35 fedora_localhost--live-root -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       7 Feb 11 08:35 fedora_localhost--live-swap -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       7 Feb 11 08:35 luks-abcdef01-2345-6789-abcd-ef0123456789 -> ../dm-0
```

Answer (score -5):

mount -o remount,size=10g /dev/shm

Comment: Please explain it.

Comment: Thanks, but swap is changed again to 3.9 G after reboot

Comment: @user2439245 You've to modify the "/etc/fstab" file for applying as permanent

Comment: Modified /etc/fstab, but not applying after reboot

Comment: UUID=426e2caf-6d27-4b0a-9bd4-dd7d63102e7c swap                    swap    defaults,size=10G        0 0