# How to resize swap file in CentOS 7

Tags: swap

I see a number of explanations referring to resizing swap partitions; however, I cannot find one that explains how to "resize" an existing swap file.

My existing /swapfile1 is 512 MB.

I want to increase it to 1 GB.

Is it simpler to create a new swap file and delete this one following instructions here [How to increase swap space on RHEL7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499859/how-to-increase-swap-space-on-rhel7)

Answer (score 8):

Actually yes, it's simpler to delete the swap file and create a new one.

1. Deactivate the swap

   ```
   swapoff /swapfile1
   ```
2. Delete the swap file and create a new one

   ```
   rm -f /swapfile1 && dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile1 bs=1024 count=1024000
   ```
3. Set up the swap file

   ```
   mkswap /swapfile1
   ```
4. Reactivate the swap

   ```
   swapon /swapfile1
   ```